# How to get msg and metadata command to compile with the variable value

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

I have a device which is connected to thingsboard cloud via HTTP Post, and have the data being passed through a new rule chain (couldn't get the integration to work) and unsure of how to get msg. to be a variable after the msg eg msg.VARIABLE = sensor1.value, I have the following data snippet:
`{ "S1": { "description": "S1", "id": "0000000000000000", "type": "MB", "addr": "1", "item1": { "value": "65.3", "unit": "Humidity", "alarm": "0", "min": "0.0", "max": "100.0", "hys": "10.0" }, "item2": { "value": "1008.4", "unit": "AirPressure", "alarm": "0", "min": "0.0", "max": "10160.0", "hys": "1.0" } }`

Is there a way to get msg to output  "Humidity":"65.3"

Thanks Cameron

and is being processed by the script:
`var s1Data = s.S1;
var s1Item1 = s1Data.item1;
var s1Item2 = s1Data.item2;

```
Newmsg.s1Sensor1Unit= s1Item1.unit;
Newmsg.s1Sensor2Unit= s1Item2.unit;
Newmsg.s1Item1value =s1Item1.value;
Newmsg.s1Item2value =s1Item2.value;`
```

which produces the following output:
 `"msg": { "s1Sensor1Unit": "Humidity", "s1Sensor2Unit": "AirPressure", "s1Item1value": "65.3", "s1Item2value": "1008.4" }`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution :

```
var s = Monitor.S;
var s1Data = s.S1;//s[key]
var s1Item1 = s1Data.item1;
var s1Item2 = s1Data.item2;
Newmsg[s1Item1.unit] = s1Item1.value;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).